# javascript paste text into a Textarea remove (CR) from CRLF

Tags: javascript, html, input

I need to preserve the line breaks of an text input inserted in my javascript front-end page, after being pasted into a Textarea input

this is what happens if I debug the value contained in the onSumbit() method of the textarea
[image: notepad++ decoded text]

I need to have CRLF but the image clearly shows that the CarriageReturn (CR) have been removed from the text inserted and only LineFeed (LF) is still present.

I've tried to add the css property white-space: pre-wrap to the textarea but that didn't work.

**How can I preserve the CRLF of the text?**

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where are you trying to encode the text to base64? If you are doing it in the frontend using Javascript to take the value, you should know that the value contains only LF. If you are doing it in the backend after a body submit by POST then yes, the value contains CRLF and something is wrong.

But my guess from your issue description is that you are in the first -frontend- case, so it's not the encoding to blame.

So, when you are getting the value from the textarea, you can do something like

```
value.replace(/\r\n/g, "\n").replace(/\n/g, "\r\n")
```

to always get CRLF.

Comment: yes I'm in the front-end case, could you explain me why the value contains only LF? Before putting it into the textarea it does contains CRLF so why and when is javascript removing it?

Comment: That's what the standards are saying. If you place CRLFs, they are converted to LFs after editing. You can verify  with a console.log after a value change. You can type something like console.log({v: e.target.value}), so you can clearly see the control characters. You can also try to add a default value and then to convert to base64 without editing. You should have your precious CRs.

Comment: Is there a way to change this standard ?

Comment: There seems to be no way of it. My suggestion is that, when you read the text, 1) convert all CRLF to LF and then 2) convert all LF to CRLF. This way you'll always get CRLF lines in every case (content edited or not, initial value contained CRLF or LF). Something like value.replace(/\r\n/g, "\n").replace(/\n/g, "\r\n") should be enough